Linear Algebra Done Right 4th Edition, Section 5E, Exercise 6
Problem
Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $S, T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ commute. Prove that there exist $\alpha, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$\text{range}(S - \alpha I) + \text{range}(T - \lambda I) \neq V.$$
My Thoughts
I know that since $S$ and $T$ commute, then $S$ and $T$ share an eigenvector $v$. Presumably $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues associated with $v$ with respect to $S$ and $T$ respectively. However, I'm not sure where to go from here.

The eigenspace of $S$ corresponding to $\alpha$ is $\ker (S-\alpha I)$. Since $S,T$ commute $\ker (S-\alpha I)$ is invariant under $T$. So $T\vert_{\ker (S-\alpha I)}$ will also have an eigenvector $v \in \ker (S-\alpha I)$ possibly with a different eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then both $\operatorname{range}(S-\alpha I)$ and  $\operatorname{range}(T-\lambda I)$ will not contain eigenvector $v$; since $v \in V$, $\operatorname{range}(S-\alpha I)+\operatorname{range}(T-\lambda I)\neq V$.

Could you explain why both $\text{range}(S - \alpha I)$ and $\text{range}(S - \lambda I)$ will not contain eigenvector $v$? I don't quite follow.

Think of it this way: $V=\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$. One basis vector $v_r \in \ker (S-\alpha I)$. We can express any vector $v \in V$ as $a_1v_1 +\ldots+a_r v_r+ \ldots+ a_n v_n$; then $(S-\alpha I)v=a_1(S-\alpha I)v_1+ \ldots + 0 v_r + \ldots + a_n (S-\alpha I)v_n $. Even if $(S-\alpha I)v_1,\ldots,(S-\alpha I)v_n$ are independent, $\operatorname{range}(S-\alpha I)$ is a subspace of $V$.

I agree that $\text{range}(S-\alpha I)$ is a subspace of $V$ that is not equal to $V$, but $\text{rang}(S - \lambda I)$ could make up for the 'missing' dimension.

Not if $S,T$ are commuting (btw I think you mean $\operatorname{range}(T-\lambda I)$). Think about it for just a moment.

If is enough to consider the case where $V= \mathbb F^n$ for some algebraically closed $\mathbb F$.  Now $S$ and $T$ are simultaneously upper triangularizable, $\mathbf B^{-1}S\mathbf B =R^{(S)}$ and $\mathbf B^{-1}T\mathbf B =R^{(T)}$, since they commute and our field is algebraically closed.  This means that up to conjugation the $n$th component of all vectors is zero for all $v\in\text{image}\big(S-\alpha I\big)$ and all $v \in \text{image}\big(T-\lambda I\big)$, with $\alpha: =R^{(S)}_{n,n}$ and $\lambda:=R^{(T)}_{n,n}$,  hence $\text{image}\big(S-\alpha I\big)+ \text{image}\big(T-\lambda I\big)\neq V$.
More formally, suppose $\text{image}\big(S-\alpha I_n\big)+ \text{image}\big(T-\lambda I_n\big)= V $
$\implies \big(S-\alpha I_n\big)X + \big(T-\lambda I_n\big)Y = I_n$ for some $X,Y$.  But the above tells us there is a $\mathbf 0 \neq \mathbf w\in \ker \Big\{\big(S-\alpha I_n\big)^T\Big\}\bigcap \ker \Big\{\big(T-\lambda I_n\big)^T\Big\}$
$\implies \mathbf 0^T = \mathbf w^T \Big(\big(S-\alpha I\big)X + \big(T-\lambda I\big)Y\Big) = \mathbf w^T I=\mathbf w^T$ which is a contradiction.

it isn't strictly necessary, but the equation $\big(S-\alpha I_n\big)X + \big(T-\lambda I_n\big)Y = I_n$ as well as the problem posed by the existence of a common "zero" should remind people of weak nullstellensatz
